# No notification on UK Transit Visa

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I applied for UK Travel Visa on 6th Dec 2018. I did not get receive even a single notification mail on my application (not even application receipt mail). I called support center (paid service), an executive told that they are working on my application and he does't have more information in this regard.

Any has got any notification mail in last three weeks? Do they (UK Embassy) work during Christmas week? Any one had similar experience?

Comment: Sorry about your situation however In reality the best information you got was from the support center. Any answer you receive from here about someone else circumstance won’t change your situation.

Comment: If you applied through a visa application center, you might have to create an account on the TLScontact site where you could track the status of your application.

Answer (score 1):

> Do they (UK Embassy) work during Christmas week?

The UK Embassy in each country typically observes the National Holidays of both the host nation and the British National Holidays.

That said, [In line with the Home Office’s intention to process all entry clearance applications submitted overseas in Sheffield](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=2bd3bca5-c21c-41b7-84d6-cb18342ea77a), all visa applications submitted abroad will now be scanned and sent to the Home Office in Sheffield for processing.

Depending on where you are applying from and your local [Visa Application Center](https://www.gov.uk/find-a-visa-application-centre), you can expect that there will be no processing on your local National Holidays and UK National Holidays, including Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

Emails are sent from the Proviso System, triggered by events during the process. Should you not receive a notification or updates, it can be nothing more than a heavier than usual workload, or a glitch at the Proviso. The automated information management system indicates processing, not decisions.

You took the appropriate step in contacting the help centre (fee based) which, as you experienced, can advise on an application's general status, but not provide specifics or details.

UKVI staff do not work on Saturdays, Sundays, or [UK public holidays](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays). So, this holiday week, offices will be closed Tuesday, December 25, and Wednesday, December 26 (Boxing Day), and closed again next week on Tuesday, January 1.